# anchor link to select a particular value in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

The problem I am trying to solve is this
page1.html

```
<a href="/foo"></a>
```

foo.html

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.listvalues">
    <option id="{{item.value}}" ng-repeat="item" in ctrl.availableValues" value="{{item.value}}">item.displayName</option>
</select>
```

My goal is to get the anchor link in page1.html to link to foo and select a value from the list. (value1)

```
<a href="/foo#value1"></a>
```

Any idea how i can solve this ??

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Edited the question. My expectation is to link to the page and select a particular value from the dropdown list.

Comment: So when the page is called if the value of an item is in the hash, you want that value preselected from the the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to grab the hash value from the URL in order to do this. In your controller, make sure you're injecting $window and then you can use $window.location.hash to retrieve it. It will be prefixed with the # use:

```
$window.location.hash.substring(1)
```

to get the value in your controller, then assigning the value to the corresponding property in your model should take care of the rest.